# Django - Calculating age until a date in DB

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm new to Django. Please help me with this issue.

This is the model that I want to write query on.

```
class ReservationFrame(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    information = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The json field (ReservationFrame.information) has this format

```
{
    upper_age_limit: 22,
    lower_age_limit: 30
}
```

I want to calculate the age of login user until ReservationFrame.start_at, and return the corresponding ReservationFrame if lower_age_limit <= user.age <= upper_age_limit

The formula that I'm using to calculate age is

```
start_at.year - born.year - ((start_at.month, start_at.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

I'm using annotate but getting errors.

```
person_birthday = request.user.person.birthday
frames_without_age_limit = reservation_frames.exclude(Q(information__has_key = 'upper_age_limit')&Q(information__has_key = 'lower_age_limit'))
reservation_frames = reservation_frames.annotate(
    age=ExtractYear('start_at') - person_birthday.year - Case(When((ExtractMonth('start_at'), ExtractDay('start_at')) < (person_birthday.month, person_birthday.day), then=1), default=0))
reservation_frames = reservation_frames.filter(
    Q(information__lower_age_limit__lte = F('age'))|
    Q(information__lower_age_limit=None)
)
reservation_frames = reservation_frames.filter(
    Q(information__upper_age_limit__gte = F('age'))|
    Q(information__upper_age_limit=None)
)
```

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ExtractMonth' and 'int'

Comment: Try using the lesser(lt) and greater(gt) syntax to make your comparison. Like `When(start_at__month__lt = person_birthday.month)`. Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relational operators like <,>, <=,>=,== are not allowed in [Django conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).
So you should implement your logic using querysets and chain conditions.
also, you can change that lexical comparison into a simpler logical comparison.
like this:

> (A,B) < (X,Y) --->  (A<X) OR ((A==X) AND (B<Y))

try like this. it should work!

```
reservation_frames = reservation_frames.annotate(
age=ExtractYear('start_at') - person_birthday.year - Case(
    When(Q(start_at__month__lt=person_birthday.month)|(Q(start_at__month=person_birthday.month) & Q(start_at__day__lt=person_birthday.day)), then=1),
    default=0))
```

Comment: Sorry Pavithra, your code worked. But I have another problem with the next query. Could you please help me with that too?

`reservation_frames = reservation_frames.filter(Q(information__lower_age_limit__lte = F('age'))|Q(information__lower_age_limit=None))`

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not int`

Comment: I tried `str(F('age'))` and the error disappeared. But I still think that something is not right cuz the query results is not what I expected

Comment: since JSONField is brand new to django, I guess __lte chain comparison doesn't work with json inner keys. can you try this way: `information__lte = {'lower_age_limit' : F('age')}`

Comment: btw it seems overkill to me that using JSONField to just store those only two age limits. if you can store those limits as separate two IntegerFields, you will be able to avoid many querying complications. cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for your supports. I'm thinking about using a for loop instead to avoid complicate queries =)))